# Modificar htaccess para obtener URLs "amigables"

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Edito:

De momento las soluciones no me han funcionado. La única que estoy probando y que veo que sí que me accede a la URL es con el siguiente código:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^XboxOne/([0-9]+) single.php?id=$1
```

Esto me deja una URL en localhost como: `http://localhost/xboxone/XboxOne/258`

El problema que me estoy encontrando es que la ID no me la coge bien, con lo cual me devuelve un array nulo de la base de datos.

---

Tengo un pequeño problema con las URLs de mi página web. Mis enlaces son del estilo:

```
http://www.lalalalala.com/single.php?ID=224

http://www.lalalalala.com/noticias/noticias.php?ID=105
```

La primera es para fichas técnicas de juegos, y la segunda y la que más me preocupa es la de noticias. Por lo que me han comentado no es lo mismo tenerla como la tengo yo a tenerla por ejemplo

```
http://www.lalalalala.com/noticias/las-mejores-ofertas-de-xbox
```

El problema viene a que he leído que hay que tener mucho cuidado y hacer un respaldo, sin embargo no es esto lo que me preocupa, más bien el hecho de que los enlaces anteriores dejen de funcionar y que no consigan redirigirse. La web está abierta desde noviembre, y suelo publicar a diario con lo que tengo esa inquietud de que los enlaces dejen de funcionar.

Me gustaría saber si recomendáis el cambio y cómo proceder, tengo entendido que en algo puede mejorar el SEO.

Comment: si es wordpress, las viejas urls debieran redirigir a las nuevas

Answer (score 1):

Buenas tardes. Primeramente apuntar que seguramente puedas seguir utilizando las anteriores rutas, pese a que es difícil saberlo sin decir que FW utilizas, si utilizas algún enrutador, etc.

Quitando lo último para utilizarlas debes activar el módulo `mod_rewrite`.

A continuación deberías modificar tu .htaccess siguiento el ejemplo:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# redirect "/section.php?id=xxx" to "/section/xxx"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/section\.php\?id=([0-9]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /section/%1? [R=301,L]

# internally rewrite "/section/xxx" to "/section.php?id=xxx"
RewriteRule ^section/([0-9]+)$ /section.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Sacado de [éste hilo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28168375/how-to-write-htaccess-rewrite-rule-for-seo-friendly-url) hilo del SO oficial.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, a priori no parece complicado...entiendo que sólo tendría que modificar `/noticias.php?ID=xxx`, sin embargo la segunda parte me deja dudas, la parte de `/section/xxx`, siendo xxx un número, entiendo que la URL quedaría algo así `/section/99`, cuando lo que me gustaría es que aparece el título del artículo por ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Hola aquí un ejemplo sencillo.

Como url no amigable tenemos por ejemplo:

> http://www.tuweb.com/users.php?id=1

Y como url amigable entenderíamos algo como esto:

> http://www.tuweb.com/juan

Para conseguirlo solo creamos el archivo htacces y agregamos lo siguiente

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.tuweb.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://tuweb.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ users.php?user=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ users.php?user=$1
```

Y modificar los links hacia los perfiles de los usuarios añadiendo la url amigable en vez de la no amigable.

Comment: No lo he probado todavía, quería hacer pruebas en localhost pero no lo he conseguido. Lo que no encuentro es el fichero htaccess, supongo que tendría que crearlo, pero si algo fuese mal, con eliminar el fichero bastaría?

Comment: asi es es crear el archivo y si te salen mas las pruebas borras, recargas tu localhost (cierras y abres tu servicio apache)  y listo, si te sirvio no olvides calificar

Comment: Sólo me ha funcionado el código que indicó en la edición del primer post, que es algo que encontré poco después, pero sigo teniendo problemas.

Comment: Describeme tu problema para poderte ayudar

Comment: A través de la URL paso el número de ID, por ejemplo `single.php?ID=21` refleja que en la base de datos tiene que buscar el ID 21, sin embargo no me lo recoge, y me devuelve un array vacío.

Comment: una consulta amigo, tienes activo el mod_rewrite en tu servidor apache?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55440/discussion-between-bygroxd-and-jetlagfox).