# Hipervínculos, pasar título del contenido a la URL

Tags: php, pretty-urls

Hola tengo una duda de como puedo hacer para que las urls me muestre el título de su contenido el la barra del navegador, es decir si yo por ejemplo tengo el siguiente enlace..
`<a href="noticias.php?contenido=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" >Trump insulta a latinos </a>`

En ese enlace la url mostraria..
 `mipagina.com/noticias.php?contenido=2`

En el archivo php hago una consulta a la base de datos en la tabla noticias  que me muestre los campos con el id= a 2,en esos campos hay uno que es el título de la noticias ese es el que me interesa que aparesca en la URL ejemplo...

`Mipagina.com/noticias/Trump insulta a latinos`

Trump insulta a latinos seria el campo título de la tabla noticias , como se podría generar estas URLS ?

Cualquiero ayuda o tips se lo agradezco y disculpen si la pregunta no aparece bien estructurada lo que pasa es que estoy publicando desde un celular.

Answer (score 0):

Eso se llama "[URL Semántica o Amigable](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_sem%C3%A1ntica)" y se hace mediante el archivo .htaccess.

[Aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/55209/modificar-htaccess-para-obtener-urls-amigables) podes encontrar ayuda